# Why here we have $3 | p-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Below is a proof that there are infinite primes in the form $1 (\mod 6)$ :

Suppose that $x\not\equiv 1 (\mod 3)$. Then $x^2 +x +1 \equiv 1 (\mod 6)$. Let $p|x^2 +x + 1$. Then $(x^2 + x + 1)(x – 1) = x^3 – 1 \equiv 0 (\mod p)$. Thus $x^3\equiv 1 (\mod p)$. As above, $3|p – 1$, and so $p \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$.

Now that there are only finitely many prime $p = 1 (\mod 6)$, and label suppose them $p_1, .., p_n$. Then consider $N = (6p_1 ... p_n)^2 + (6p_1 ... p_n) + 1$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $N$. By the above, $p  \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$. Also, $N$ is odd, so p must be odd too, and so $p  \equiv  1 (\mod 6)$. But $p$ must be different from all the $p_i$, since $p|N$ but $p_i \nmid N$ for all i = 1, ..., n. So there must be infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 (\mod 6)$.

All the props is flood, except that I don’t understand the last sentence of the first paragraph: As above, $3|p – 1$, and so $p \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$.

Pls enlighten me, why here we have $3|p-1$?

Comment: If $3 | (p-1)$ then $p-1 \equiv 0 (mod 3)$ so $p \equiv 1 (mod 3)$.

Comment: $x^3\equiv 1$, $x\not\equiv 1 \bmod p$ imply $x$ has order $3$ mod $p$ and so $3$ divides $p-1$ by Lagrange. It remains to prove that $x\not\equiv 1 \bmod p$ and this follows from $p \mid x^2+x+1$ and $p>3$ by Fermat.

Comment: $p  \equiv 1 (\mod 3)\iff p=1+3N$

Comment: @lhf of course.. I must be sleeping. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much group theory do you know?

That there is an $x \not = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $x^3 =1$, implies that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ has a subgroup of order $3$, namely, $\langle x \rangle =\{x,x^2,1\}$. So $3$ must divide $|(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}|$. But because $p$ is prime, the equation
$|(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}| = p-1$ holds, so $3|(p-1)$.

And that $p|(x^2+x+1)$ implies indeed $x \not \equiv_p 1$ for all primes $p >3$; otherwise if $x \equiv_p 1$ then the equation $x^2+x+1 \equiv_p 3$ would hold, which would imply that $x^2+x+1$ cannot divide $p$ after all.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not the OP, but I was still curious.